# Simulating data to fit a mediation model

Tags: r, regression, simulation, random-generation, mediation

I am interested in finding a procedure to simulate data that are consistent with a specified mediation model.  According to the general linear structural equation model framework for testing mediation models first outlined by [Barron and Kenny (1986)](https://umdrive.memphis.edu/grelyea/public/PUBH%207152-Stat%20Methods%20II/Chapter%2010/Mediation/Baron_&_Kenny_1986.pdf) and described elsewhere such as [Judd, Yzerbyt, & Muller (2013)](http://www.psor.ucl.ac.be/personal/yzerbyt/Judd%20et%20al.%20HRMSP%202013.pdf), mediation models for outcome $Y$, mediator $\newcommand{\med}{\rm med} \med$, and predictor $X$ and are governed by the following three regression equations:
\begin{align}
Y    &= b_{11} + b_{12}X + e_1                \tag{1}  \\
\med &= b_{21} + b_{22}X + e_2                \tag{2}  \\
Y    &= b_{31} + b_{32}X + b_{32} \med + e_3  \tag{3}
\end{align}
The indirect effect or mediation effect of $X$ on $Y$ through $\med$ can either be defined as $b_{22}b_{32}$ or, equivalently, as $b_{12}-b_{32}$.  Under the old framework of testing for mediation, mediation was established by testing $b_{12}$ in equation 1, $b_{22}$ in equation 2, and $b_{32}$ in equation 3.

So far, I have attempted to simulate values of $\med$ and $Y$ that are consistent with values of the various regression coefficients using `rnorm` in `R`, such as the code below:

```
x   <- rep(c(-.5, .5), 50)
med <- 4 + .7 * x + rnorm(100, sd = 1) 

# Check the relationship between x and med
mod <- lm(med ~ x)
summary(mod)

y <- 2.5 + 0 * x + .4 * med + rnorm(100, sd = 1)

# Check the relationships between x, med, and y
mod <- lm(y ~ x + med)
summary(mod)

# Check the relationship between x and y -- not present
mod <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(mod)
```

However, it seems that sequentially generating $\med$ and $Y$ using equations 2 and 3 is not enough, since I am left with no relationship between $X$ and $Y$ in regression equation 1 (which models a simple bivariate relationship between $X$ and $Y$) using this approach.  This is important because one definition of the indirect (i.e., mediation) effect is $b_{12}-b_{32}$, as I describe above.

Can anyone help me find a procedure in R to generate variables $X$, $\med$, and $Y$ that satisfy constraints that I set using equations 1, 2, and 3?

Answer (score 4):

This is quite straightforward.  The reason you have no relationship between $x$ and $y$ using your approach is because of the code:

```
y <- 2.5 + 0 * x + .4 * med + rnorm(100, sd = 1)
```

If you want some relationship between $x$ and $y$ even when ${\rm med}$ is included (that is, you want *partial* mediation), you would simply use a non-zero value for $b_{32}$ instead.  For example, you could substitute the following code for the above:

```
y <- 2.5 + 3 * x + .4 * med + rnorm(100, sd = 1)
```

Thus, $b_{32}$ has been changed from $0$ to $3$.  (Of course some other, specific value would probably be more relevant, depending on your situation, I just picked $3$ off the top of my head.)

---

*Edit:*
With respect to the marginal $x\rightarrow y$ relationship being non-significant, that is just a function of [statistical power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power).  Since the causal force of $x$ is passed entirely through ${\rm med}$ in your original setup, you have lower power than you might otherwise.  Nonetheless, the effect is still *real* in some sense.  When I ran your original code (after having set the seed using `90` as a value that I again just picked off the top of my head), I did get a significant effect:

```
set.seed(90)
x <- rep(c(-.5, .5), 50)
med <- 4 + .7 * x + rnorm(100, sd = 1) 

# Check the relationship between x and med
mod <- lm(med ~ x)
summary(mod)

y <- 2.5 + 0 * x + .4 * med + rnorm(100, sd = 1)

# Check the relationships between x, med, and y
mod <- lm(y ~ x + med)
summary(mod)

# Check the relationship between x and y -- not present
mod <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(mod)

...
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   3.8491     0.1151  33.431   <2e-16 ***
x             0.5315     0.2303   2.308   0.0231 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

...
```

To get more power, you can increase the $N$ you are using, or use smaller error values (i.e., use `sd=` values less than the default `1` in the `rnorm()` calls).

Comment: gung, thanks for your answer.  I suppose my question might be a little ambiguous.  What I want is not a relationship between x and y in model 3 (which is what you've done), but in model 1 (Y = b11 + b12 * X + e1).  I have clarified my question to this effect.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Is it possible to directly specify the size of the population effect for coefficient b12?

Comment: Your question at this point is what would be: what is the population correlation between $x$ & $y$ in general. I wonder if that might be best asked as a new question, as I'm not sure off the top of my head. In the simplest case, where all 3 variables ($x$, $med$, $y$) are normally distributed, & the relationship b/t $x$ & $y$ is *fully* mediated, then $\rho_{x,y} = \rho_{x,med}*\rho_{med,y}$. However, it's more complex if the distributions aren't normal (eg, your $x$ is equal frequencies of $-.5$ & $+.5$), or w/ more complex mediational situations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a  paper on how to model simple mediation in [Caron & Valois (2018)](https://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol14-2/p147/p147.pdf):
There R code is

```
  x <- rnorm(n)
  em <- sqrt(1-a^2)
  m <- a*x + em*rnorm(n)
  ey2 <- sqrt(ey)
  y <- cp*x + b*m + ey2*rnorm(n)
  data <- as.data.frame(cbind(x, m, y))
```

You just have to specify $n$ (the sample size), $a$, $b$ and $c'$ (direct effect). The advantage here is that you will model standardized coefficients so you'll know their effect sizes. They also included code to unstandardize, carry the Baron & Kenny, Sobel and Bca bootstrap.

References

Caron, P.-O., & Valois, P. (2018). A computational description of simple mediation analysis. The Quantitative Methods for Psychology, 14, 147-158. doi:10.20982/tqmp.14.2.p147